# How can I get an EPS or PDF to open in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf, eps

Just downloaded some vector graphics from Shutterstock for my landscape design project in Illustrator. When I open the document I see a blank sheet so how do I get the downloaded file (PDF or EPS) into Illustrator?

Comment: err.. really? File Open within Illustrator (just like every other application known to man) or double-click the EPS file.

Comment: have done this, but a blank sheet is downloaded. No vectors just a blank sheet.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then. Illustrator opens files just like any other application. If the file is blank.. then it must be blank (or colored white and you simply aren't seeing the white shapes).

Comment: Tell us what you have tried, what steps and alternative ways of opening them you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the EPS or PDF in Illustrator I would try `View -> Outline` shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.  The blank file you're seeing may be a result of no color or outlines applied:

[image]

Preview mode:

[image]

Outline Mode:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Illustrator opens files the same way any other application will open a file.

- Double-click the application file to launch the application and open the file (in this case, you would double-click the EPS file)
- From within the application choose `File > Open` and then navigate to your file, highlight it and click the `Open` button.

There is nothing special about how Illustrator opens compatible files.